# Error during create X509Certificate2 object on IIS server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, x509certificate2

I have a problem with create X509Certificate2 object.

```
private void OpenKey()
{
    if (!File.Exists(KeyFile))
    {
        return;
    }

    cert = new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(KeyFile), KeyPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
    securityKey = new X509SecurityKey(cert);
}
```

On localhost this work fine, on dev server too but on production server I have error:

```
Exception: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: An internal error occurred. at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr) at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._LoadCertFromBlob(Byte[] rawData, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean persistKeySet, SafeCertContextHandle& pCertCtx) at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils.LoadCertFromBlob(Byte[] rawData, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean persistKeySet, SafeCertContextHandle pCertCtx) at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromBlob(Byte[] rawData, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(Byte[] rawData, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
```

I work on .NET Framework 4.5.2.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: The user may not have enough permissions to persist the private key in machine store.

Answer (score 0):

@Hazrelle is correct in comments, application pool doesn't have permissions to persist private keys in Local Machine store (which requires admin/system permissions).

And, actually, you shall not persist certificates and their keys you load dynamically and do not have intentions to persist them. I have blog post which explains this in more details: https://www.pkisolutions.com/handling-x509keystorageflags-in-applications/

To solve your problem, you should skip all storage flags in constructor, i.e.:

```
cert = new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(KeyFile), KeyPassword);
```

and keep certificate reference somewhere in class, so you can call

```
cert.Dispose();
```

after finishing using the certificate (after signing JWT) to delete private key material from filesystem.

Comment: I try your suggest, but it still doesn't work. Try with "Load User Profile" set on False and True, same result.